# Domain registered with Google returns more IP than specified

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite

The domain has only TWO A records.

```
@ 173.X.X.X
* 173.X.X.X
```

But `dig` returns FOUR. It seems Google added some A records, and my IP even not the first. This's causing slow, how to resolve this?

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
X.com.  928 IN  A   216.239.38.21
X.com.  928 IN  A   173.X.X.X
X.com.  928 IN  A   216.239.34.21
X.com.  928 IN  A   216.239.36.21
```

Comment: Google or Godaddy? I wasn't aware Google is a domain name registrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a problem with Godaddy's nameserver. Now I'm using a different nameserver and it works perfectly.

**UPDATE:**
Oh, no. The new nameserver is buggy too, just in a different way. I've contacted Godaddy, lets wait for them.

**UPDATE:**
Yes. Godaddy resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually checked your DNS control panel? It's likely that, for whatever reason, there are 4 A records listed for @ (the domain itself). Delete the A records that you don't want and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, I logged on Godaddy, and it's only two A records as listed above.